# How to override Django LocaleMiddleware with a user preference

Tags: python, django

I am using LocaleMiddleware to automatically set the language for the user. However I want the user to be able to set a preference that overrides the locale if he or she wants too

It seems the Django LocaleMiddleware doesn't allow this?

Comment: The error was: LocaleMiddleware should come AFTER sessions...

Answer (score 0):

https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/utils/translation/trans_real.py#L366

I see that django checks for session variable, cookie to set language.

You should probably set `django_language = 'language_code'`